# Root question on derivates

Tags: derivatives

Let's define $f(x)$ as a function, Then,

If $f(x_1)=0$ and $f'(x_2)=0$, what is the inequality sign between $x_1$ and $x_2$?

$f'(x)$ is the derivate of $f(x)$ here.

Note: I don't have much knowledge on the technical terms, so please edit my question if you see any mistake.

Comment: What's the question?  Why would you think there was some absolute relation between $x_1,x_2$ in this situation?

Comment: Actually, we can not conclude anything...

Comment: I think I generalize my actual question too much that we can not conclude anything as I understand. I will delete the question and try hard to solve my actual question. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say in general whether $x_1\leq x_2$ or $x_1\geq x_2$. Take for example $f(x)=x^2-1$.  Then $f(1)=f(-1)=f'(0)=0$ and $-1<0<1$.

Comment: What if $x_1,x_2\geq0$?

Comment: @Bright Chancellor There is a similar counterexample: take $f(x)=(x-1)(x-3)$. Then $f(1)=f'(2)=f(3)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your examples, I got it.